# How to change jquery plugin's attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, attributes

For example I have jquery plugin and I call an init method with some atrributes like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#someid').somePlugin({
                           animation : 'fadeIn',
                           speed : '1000',
                           easing : 'swing'
                        });
});
```

Let's pretend I have also html link on a page. Is it possible somehow to change attribute values of this plugin's init function by clicking for example on html link? 
So, by clicking on the link I want to change for example speed attribute without page refreshing. If this possible, what is the best way to implement this action?

Or maybe I should change something in my plugin's code first.
Plugin's code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        somePlugin: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                speed : 500,
                animation : 'fadeIn',
                easing : false
            }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var speed = options.speed;
            var easing = options.easing;
            var animation = options.animation;

            return this.each(function() {
                var obj = $(this);
                //some action here 
            });
        }   
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This depends entirely on how the plugin is written! Passing a new object or just passing strings, like you would in say jQuery UI etc. does'nt work if the plugin does'nt support it.

Comment: @adeneo, you should post that as an answer, since the others are incomplete or just incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
$('#someid').somePlugin('option', 'animation', 5000);
```

Additionally, you can change multiple options at once via:

```
$('#someid').somePlugin('option', {animation: 5000, otherOption: 'blah'});
```

I should mention this only works for *certain* if you're using "official" jQuery plugins.  A lot of plugin authors adhere to this design pattern, but not all do.  Also, if you develop a plugin using the [jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://jqueryui.com/widget/), you get this functionality for free.

---

EDIT: Since the OP is authoring his own plugin, we can show an example of how to facilitate this functionality with a custom plugin.  Taken directly from the [jQuery plugin authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods):

```
(function( $ ){
  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
      //Extend options here with your 
      //defaults and init your plugin
    },
    option: function( key, value ){
       options[key] = value;
    }
  };

  $.fn.somePlugin = function( method ) {
    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      //some error that method doesnt exist
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

$('div').somePlugin({someOption: true});
//..later
$('div').somePlugin('option', 'someOption', false);
```

Comment: **Quote:** _"...only works **for certain** if you're using "**official**" jQuery plugins"_ ~ An "official" jQuery plugin?  [There's no such thing](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). The [jQuery Validate plugin written by Jörn Zaefferer, a member of the jQuery and jQueryUI development teams](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), doesn't even have that ability:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lqpjy/

Comment: I guess I should of said official "jQuery UI" plugins?  Better?  Just because someone is a member of the jQuuery dev team and they create a plugin, doesn't mean the plugin is "official".  These are the plugins officially supported and documented by jQuery UI team: http://api.jqueryui.com/category/widgets/.

Comment: Yes, agreed, unless there is some kind of certification process, there is nothing that makes any plugin "official".  Since the question is not specifically about jQueryUI, or mentions jQueryUI, your point is moot.

Comment: Hence, the special note at the end of my answer.

Comment: Which means just ignore the answer, since the OP is not asking about jQueryUI.

Comment: I added plugin's code. What should I change or add here to make a possibility to change options after init? I will be very appreciated if someone will help me.

Comment: So, If I understood you right, in init method I should extend options and write plugin's actions in return this.each() method and then, if I will create my own method (for example 'someMethod') I can use it in init method like this - $('div').someMethod(); That's right?

Comment: Not quite.   In this example, you'd call the other methods by $('div').somePlugin('someMethod').  This is kind of a more advanced topic, and each plugin design pattern is  really dependent on your requirement.  I'd strongly recommend you checking out the large amount of resources revolving around this subject including: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/ and http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring